# Counting digits, whitespaces and other characters

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*Counts digits, white numbers, others*/

main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite=nother=0;
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        ndigit[i]=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        if(c>='0' && c<=9)
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if(c=='void' || c=='\n' || c=='\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
    printf("digits= ");
    printf("%d", ndigit[i]);
    printf("whitespace=%d, other=%d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Comment: and what';s your question?

Comment: `if(c>='0' && c<=9)` At least in ASCII that's never true. (You want `'9'`, of course. And whitespace isn't just something that you can count; you can also use it to format and organise your source code.)

Comment: void is for a blank space. I tried putting it in the form c==' ' ....     but it didnt compile so I used void

Comment: I think understanding arrays is the first part of it

Comment: You should Google isdigit and isspace. And you definitely should compile with a higher warning Level and listen to the Compiler warnings!

Comment: what can i put in the place of void

Comment: @ThierryM You can use a space `' '` instead of `'void'`. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three changes:

1. `if(c>='0' && c<=9)` to `if(c>='0' && c<='9')`
2. Change `c=='void'` to `c==' '`
3. Printing the count of each digit should also be inside a loop.

   ```
   for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
       printf("%d ", ndigit[i]);
   ```

**Final code**:

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*Counts digits, white numbers, others*/

main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite=nother=0;
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        ndigit[i]=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        if(c>='0' && c<='9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if(c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
    printf("digits= ");
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf("%d ", ndigit[i]);
    printf("\nwhitespace=%d, other=%d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
[tthangavel@wtl-lview-7 test]$ ./a.out
43n lkj1234;la sdf;akspjfoiwqe
asdf;lkq324m n;afds
digits= 0 1 2 3 3 0 0 0 0 0
whitespace=6, other=37
[tthangavel@wtl-lview-7 test]$
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. the output for ndigits isnt as expected

Comment: It outputs the count of each digit starting from `0`. What do expect?

Comment: 0123300000 isnt the number of digits

Comment: `0 1 2 3 3 0 0 0 0 0` is the count of digit `0`, digit `1`, digit `2`, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot. i understand now.

Comment: how can I add style to my program